How to get Log4J "StatusLogger" output with timestamps?
I have activated Log4J debugging. But the debug lines have no timestamp. This confuses me because in the official examples they don't seem to configure anything either, but DO have timestamps:
From https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#status-messages
2011-11-23 17:08:00,769 DEBUG Generated plugins in 0.003374000 seconds

My output does NOT have timestamps. See my partial xtail of startup logs below. Log4J StatusLogger output at bottom.
*** /drives/x/logfiles/Tomcat9/catalina.2024-08-19.log ***
2024-08-19 11:10:38.486 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.85
2024-08-19 11:10:38.486 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jan 5 2024 08:28:07 UTC
2024-08-19 11:10:38.486 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.85.0
2024-08-19 11:10:38.486 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows Server 2022
2024-08-19 11:10:38.486 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
2024-08-19 11:10:38.486 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
2024-08-19 11:10:38.486 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             c:\program files\java\jdk
2024-08-19 11:10:38.486 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.20+8-LTS
2024-08-19 11:10:38.486 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Azul Systems, Inc.
2024-08-19 11:10:38.486 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Apache_Software_Foundation\Tomcat9
2024-08-19 11:10:38.486 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Apache_Software_Foundation\Tomcat9
2024-08-19 11:10:38.518 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Apache_Software_Foundation\Tomcat9
2024-08-19 11:10:38.518 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Apache_Software_Foundation\Tomcat9
2024-08-19 11:10:38.518 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Apache_Software_Foundation\Tomcat9\temp
2024-08-19 11:10:38.518 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
2024-08-19 11:10:38.518 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Apache_Software_Foundation\Tomcat9\conf\logging.properties
...
2024-08-19 11:10:38.518 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS.%1$tL %4$-7s [%2$s] %5$s%6$s%n
2024-08-19 11:10:38.518 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djavamelody.sampling-seconds=10
2024-08-19 11:10:38.518 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djavamelody.allowed-addr-pattern=127\.0\.0\.1
...
2024-08-19 11:10:38.518 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dlog4j.debug=true
2024-08-19 11:10:38.518 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dlog4j2.debug=true

...

*** /drives/x/logfiles/Tomcat9/tomcat9-stderr.2024-08-19.log ***
2024-08-19 11:10:54.158 INFO    [org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars] At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2024-08-19 11:10:54.252 INFO    [org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log] No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
DEBUG StatusLogger Using ShutdownCallbackRegistry class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry
TRACE StatusLogger Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext() found anchor class de.nexus.http.filter.SessionLoggingListener

UPDATE 2024-08-20Tue16-10-13, still broken
JARs used:
$ find WEB-INF/lib/ | sort | grep -i log4j
WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.19.0.jar
WEB-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.19.0.jar
WEB-INF/lib/log4j-layout-template-json-2.19.0.jar
WEB-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j2-impl-2.19.0.jar

I've played with it, but I am not currently using Configuration status="trace":
$ head -n3 WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- <Configuration status="trace" monitorInterval="30"> -->
<Configuration monitorInterval="30">

None of these options got me a timestamp:
2024-08-20 16:00:01.001 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dlog4j.debug=true
2024-08-20 16:00:01.001 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dlog4j2.debug=true
2024-08-20 16:00:01.001 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dlog4j2.simplelogShowContextMap=true
2024-08-20 16:00:01.001 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dlog4j2.simplelogShowlogname=true
2024-08-20 16:00:01.001 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dlog4j2.simplelogShowShortLogname=false
2024-08-20 16:00:01.001 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dlog4j2.simplelogShowdatetime=true
2024-08-20 16:00:01.001 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dlog4j2.simplelogDateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz"

(Options taken from https://logging.staged.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/simple-logger.html)
And replacing log4j-api-2.19.0.jar with log4j-api-2.20.0.jar (while keeping java-options above in place) also changed nothing: no timestamp to be seen.
UPDATE 2024-08-27Tue15-45-18, fixed
I had this line here and it didn't work...
-Dlog4j2.simplelogDateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz"
...but this one here does:
-Dlog4j2.statusLoggerDateFormat=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

So the line that works refers to a different logger type. (Which is exactly what Piotr was trying to tell me.)
And there also must be no quotes. If you DO include quotes, then you get VERBATIM quotes in the output.

I find it a little confusing that there is no sensible default for this timestamp format. -- I would have expect BOTH the "Simple Logger" type AND the "Status Logger" type to have SOMETHING as a timestamp, rather than nothing at all.

Which version of Log4j API are you using?

@PiotrP.Karwasz: 2.19.0 https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/release-notes.html#release-notes-2-19-0

Until LOG4J-3584 was implemented in version 2.20.0 there were two different sets of formatting options for status logger:

if log4j2.debug was set, the status logger used a Simple Logger that could be configured using the log4j2.statusLoggerDateFormat and related configuration properties.
if log4j2.debug was false, but you set a status attribute in your configuration file, a fixed layout was used that included a timestamp in ISO format.

To have a coherent format regardless the way Status Logger was enabled, you need to:

upgrade to 2.20.0 or later,
set the log4j2.statusLoggerDateFormat configuration property to yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS.


Impressive research. Thanks! But one thing confuses me: you wrote: Until LOG4J-3584 was implemented in version 2.20.0 But LOG4J-3584 has Jira FixVersion 2.19.0 and is also in the 2.19.0 release notes. So I'm wondering if this is the cause. I'll just try updating to 2.20.0 to check.

It's a bug in the paperwork. The PR was actually merged a couple of months after 2.19.0 was released. JIRA does not allow changes to closed issues. I can fix the release notes, though.

Works. Thanks. I upgraded all my "log4j--.jar"s to "log4j-*-2.20.0.jar"s and used these Tomcat command line options:
2024-08-27 13:22:53.675 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dlog4j2.debug=true
2024-08-27 13:22:53.675 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dlog4j2.statusLoggerDateFormat=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
FYI: There must be NO QUOTES around the date format. (Even though there is a blank in it.) Otherwise you get VERBATIM QUOTES in the output.

The quoting problem is OS specific. On UNIX the shell splits the command line into an array of arguments and passes it to Java; so -Dsomething="..." is the correct way. On Windows cmd.exe passes a single string to Java and it is up to Java to split it into arguments. See launcher.c source code.
